# ffmpeg 6 channels DTS to 6 channels AAC

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to convert a 6 channel DTS audio to a 6 (or 5.1) channel AAC. I'm using the command:

```
ffmpeg -i input.dts -ac 6 -b:a 400k output.m4a
```

But I'm getting a 2 channels audio in the end. I have tried looking into the [ffmpeg audio manipulation doc](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AudioChannelManipulation) but I can't figure it out.
So what is the proper command line to convert it?

As requested, the full output:

```
ffmpeg -y -i input.mkv -map 0:a -ac 6 -ar 48000 -ab 400k -t 30 6ch.m4a
ffmpeg version N-91618-gfe06ed22e6 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 8.2.1 (GCC) 20180813
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth
  libavutil      56. 19.100 / 56. 19.100
  libavcodec     58. 22.101 / 58. 22.101
  libavformat    58. 17.101 / 58. 17.101
  libavdevice    58.  4.101 / 58.  4.101
  libavfilter     7. 26.100 /  7. 26.100
  libswscale      5.  2.100 /  5.  2.100
  libswresample   3.  2.100 /  3.  2.100
  libpostproc    55.  2.100 / 55.  2.100
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'input.mkv':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : libebml v1.0.0 + libmatroska v1.0.0
    creation_time   : 2010-10-05T11:39:15.000000Z
  Duration: 01:31:46.54, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 12393 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x800, SAR 1:1 DAR 12:5, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 1k tbn, 47.95 tbc (default)
    Stream #0:1: Audio: dts (DTS), 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 1536 kb/s (default)
    Stream #0:2(eng): Subtitle: subrip
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (dts (dca) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, ipod, to '6ch.m4a':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.17.101
    Stream #0:0: Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, 5.1, fltp, 400 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.22.101 aac
size=     694kB time=00:00:30.01 bitrate= 189.4kbits/s speed=38.1x
video:0kB audio:680kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 2.005469%
[aac @ 0000022aca070500] Qavg: 37215.422
```

Comment: Share full log.

Comment: Shows as 6ch: `aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, 5.1`

Comment: According to meadiainfo the output is 2ch. Besides, if I issue the same command but with `-ac 2` the final file size is the same in both 6ch and 2ch.

Comment: What's the log for `ffmpeg -i output`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -vn -ac 6 -ar 48000 -ab 400k -c:a aac 6ch.m4a
```

Try this command. I always use this to convert any audio source to 6 channel AAC. And my results are good. Make sure to use the latest version of FFmpeg.

If your ffmpeg is compiled with Libfdk_AAC, use the command below.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -vn -ac 6 -ar 48000 -ab 400k -c:a libfdk_aac 6ch.m4a
```